# Does Glass support more than one level of nested custom menu items?

Tags: google-mirror-api

Does Glass support more than one level of nested custom menu items? For example:

```
-top menu item1  
  --sub-menu item1  
  --sub-menu item2  
-top menu item2  
  --sub-menu item3  
  --sub-menu item4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Medium answer: Why would you want to do this? Glass really isn't a good platform for people to do a lot of navigation through menus - it is best when the user can go through just a few choices very quickly (within 5 seconds or less).

Longer answer: See the short answer and medium answer first. Then if you have a *really good* reason for multi-level menus... you probably don't. Really. This is a bad idea. It probably means you should be doing some smart things with voice commands instead of menu items. In fact, you should probably re-think your entire approach to writing Glassware.

But if you're dead-set on making a bad user experience, you can do this sort of thing in a very limited set of circumstances.

Basically, you will want to create a [bundle of cards](https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#bundling_cards), with the cover card representing some top-level information. The other cards in the bundle would represent the top-menu items, while each sub-menu item would be an action on each of these cards. When you process a command, you would need to examine the bundleID for the card the action is performed against and, perhaps, make an extra fetch to get the top-level card if you need that for processing.

But really... don't do this. Find a better solution that isn't so hostile to your users.